# Django Relational database lookups

Tags: django, foreign-keys, models, relationship

I cant figure out how to do relationships.

I have a products model and a stores model.
A product has a foreign key to the stores.

So i would like to get the product name, and the store name in the same lookup.

Since the products model is:

```
class Products(models.Model):
  PrName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  PrCompany =  models.ForeignKey(Companies)
```

And the company model is:

```
class Companies(models.Model):
  ComName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

How do i make django return ComName (from the companies model) when i do:

```
Prs = Products.objects.filter(PrName__icontains=ss)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you get results:

```
Prs[0].PrCompany.ComName # Company name of the first result
```

If you want all the company names in a list:

```
company_names = [product.PrCompany.ComName for product in Prs]
```

Comment: For a faster list, only hit the database once:  `company_names = Prs.values_list('PrCompany__ComName')`